# jquery Autocomplete - not filtering

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to user JQuery autocomplete function with an ajax call in it, which will return the list of Strings..when i am trying to type, it is showing all the list of strings and not filtering out based on the input..Not sure where i am going wrong..Below is my autocomplete function..

```
$("#domainNameId").autocomplete({
        source : function(request, response) {
            console.log("in ajax ");
            $.ajax({
                url : "getAllDomains",
                type : "GET",
                contentType : "application/json",
                data : {
                    env : $("#environment").val()
                },
                dataType : "json",
                success : function(data) {
                     response(data); // list of strings..
                },
                error : function(x, t, m) {
                    console.trace();
                    if (!(console == 'undefined')) {
                        console.log("ERROR: " + x + t + m);
                    }
                    console.log(" At the end");
                }
            });

        },
    });
```

appreciate the help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your backend seems to always return the entire data and not do any filtering ( The service name itself is `getAllDomains`). In that case there is no need to use the function form of source option to make ajax calls.

What you're doing is sending multiple AJAX requests to the server as the user types. If your backend always returns the same data, there is no point in sending multiple requests to it. You can simply fetch the data once and then initialize the autocomplete with the response as source, then the widget will do the filtering as user types.

The docs says:

> A response callback, which expects a single argument: the data to suggest to the user. This data should be filtered based on the provided term.

So if your server doesn't do the filtering, don't use the function form to make AJAX requests.

do something like:

```js
$(function() {
  // make a one-time request
  $.ajax({
    url: "getAllDomains",
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      // init the widget with response data and let it do the filtering
      $("#domainNameId").autocomplete({
        source: data
      });
    },
    error: function(x, t, m) {
      console.trace();
      if (!(console == 'undefined')) {
        console.log("ERROR: " + x + t + m);
      }
      console.log(" At the end");
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: yea...i am returning all the domains from the server..made the changes as you said,,its working. thanks T J..

Comment: any reason why if data is a json array like `[{"name":"SIK1B"},{"name":"Nep2"},{"name":"Mtmr6"},{"name":"Pik3ca"}]` I cannot get data to populate.  If I call the functions in reverse (autocomplete before ajax) I get the OP's issue but at least the data populates.  I'm getting the data to populate with `response($.map(data, function(item) {
                        return {
                          value: item.name,
                          label: item.name
                        };
                      }));`

Comment: Ok not sure if it required this 4 year ago or if autocomplete inferred the dataType but now autocomplete will require you to add `dataType: 'json'`

Answer (score 0):

In the `success` callback, you will need to filter the `data` yourself using the `request.term` passed to the `source` function.

There is more information on the jQuery Autocomplete `source` here: https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source.

Comment: This is a bad idea... filtering is a feature built into the widget itself. there is no point in making multiple ajax calls if the server doesn't do the filtering.